# C or bitwise between #define and int

Tags: c

I have a little problem with a simple test: I have a logger with 3 levels, `LOG`, `DEBUG` and `ERROR`. At compilation I define the level error with a bitwise or operation between the values I need. But when I try to test `LEVEL` with the type message I receive, it's wrong. `5 & 2` give me `1` if the level is a constant, but if I put `LEVEL` in an `int` variable, I don't have this problem. Someone know why?

here are the definitions in **logger.h**

```
#define LOG 1
#define DEBUG 2
#define ERROR 4
#define LEVEL LOG | ERROR
```

this is the **logger.c**

```
printf("level %d\n", LEVEL);
printf("type %d\n", type);
int level = LEVEL;
printf("and %d\n", LEVEL & type);
printf("and %d\n", level & type);
printf("and %d\n", 5 & 2);
```

results

```
level 5
type 2
and 1
and 0
and 0
```

Comment: `#define LEVEL LOG | ERROR` --> `#define LEVEL (LOG | ERROR)`

Comment: Baby's first macro: `#define LEVEL (LOG | ERROR)`

Comment: To better explain these comments, preprocessor macros are simple text replacements. your first "and" printf is `printf("and %d\n", LOG | ERROR & type);`, what you want is `(LOG | ERROR) & type`

Comment: In fact you should *always* parenthesise the macro definition.

Comment: For even more clarity, `&` has precedence over `|`, which means it happens first in the absence of parenthesis. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Wow so much answers thanks for yours explanations @RobertRouhani !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro definition for `LEVEL` is not properly parenthesized.  Use this instead:

```
#define LEVEL  (LOG | ERROR)
```

With the bogus definition, here is how the `printf` statement gets expanded:

```
printf("and %d\n", LEVEL & type);
```

becomes:

```
printf("and %d\n", LOG | ERROR & type);
```

which is parsed as:

```
printf("and %d\n", LOG | (ERROR & type));
```

Not what you intend.

Always parenthesize macro definitions:

- put parentheses around all macro arguments in the expansion
- put parentheses around the complete expression to prevent precedence errors like the one above.

Comment: I will follow your advice :D. Thank you!